# Are the converses of the following special cases of conditional expectation also true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable, and $N$ be a sub sigma algebra of the underlyign sigma algebra of the sample space.

1. if $X$ is in $L^1$ and measurable wrt  $N$, then $E(X|N)=X$ a.e..

   Is it true that if $E(X|N)=X$ a.e., then $X$ must be in $L^1$ and measuarble wrt  $N$?
2. if $X$ is in $L^1$ and independent of  $N$, then $E(X|N)=EX$ a.e..

   Is it true that if $E(X|N)=EX$ a.e., then $X$ must be in $L^1$ and independent of  $N$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: $X \in L^1$ or $X \ge 0$ must be a prerequisite, as the conditional expectation isn't well-defined otherwise.

1) By definition, $E[X\mid N] = X$ is $N$-measurable.
2) No, consider $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $N = \sigma(X^2)$. Then 
$$\int I\{X^2 \in A\} X \;dP = \int I\{X \in A \cup -A\} X \; dP = 0$$
where the last equality holds because $A \cup -A$ is a symmetric set. This implies $E[X \mid \sigma(X^2)] = 0 = E[X]$, but clearly $X$ and $X^2$ aren't independent.

Comment: Thanks. what is about X that is equivalent to E(X|N)=EX a.e., if independence is too much?

Comment: I'm not aware of any condition that is equivalent to $E[X \mid N] = E[X]$. If $N = \sigma(Y)$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are square-integrable, then $E[XY] = E[E[XY \mid Y]] = E[Y E[X \mid Y]] = E[Y E[X]] = E[Y]E[X]$, so they are uncorrelated. Other than that, I don't know any useful implications.

Comment: why "both X and Y are square-integrable"?

Comment: To ensure that $E[XY]$ is well-defined.